# I just restored a recently expired domain name. Will it take the normal propagation time (48-72 hrs) for my site to be back online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

Does restoring a domain name require the same propagation time as a DNS change?  Nothing changed in my records.  My domain is from gandi.net and is handled externally by AWS.  I'm just wondering if I need to edit something somewhere or just wait.

Comment: If you need further explanation, let me know :)

Comment: You should have given the domain name because first people would have been able to test and second, the answer depends on the TLD. Typically in a gTLD world, an expired domain name **may be** on clientHold by registrar at expiration and this will be removed if domain is renewed (next time: renew it before, there is no point in waiting last minute). During this status the domain is not published on registry nameservers and hence provoke NXDOMAIN. This result is cached for the "negative TTL" which is 1 day currently for .COM. So you may have to wait up for 1 day if you are in the case described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it does.** You have to wait until some DNS server catches your domain pointing again to some nameserver or IP address.

> **Usually it takes only a few hours** depending on your domain service provider. If you feel that something is wrong, simply double check if your domain is pointing to the **right nameservers**, and if your AWS is set to handle http requests on that domain name.

Comment: Thanks, it is up now.  I was pretty sure that's all it needed but I just wanted to make sure.